# Who owns the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, millennium-falcon

The Millennium Falcon has had several different owners throughout Star Wars history as well as being in the possession of several others via theft. Post *The Force Awakens*

> When Han Solo is killed and we see Rey and Chewbacca piloting the Falcon later in the film

Who now owns the Falcon? Is there anything to suggest that

> Rey owns the Falcon, or has somehow inherited it

or do we simply not know at this stage?

Comment: @RickSanchez - not stated in canon, but as I said in my answer, **do you see *THE* Han Solo sitting down with a Lawyer to write up a will? I sure don't**.

Comment: Possession is nine-tenths of the law. The remaining ten percent probably belong to whoever has inherited Jabba the Hutts collection of IOUs.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - addressed in my answer.

Comment: I am so pleased one of my questions has ignited such debate :-)

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - isn't that how it **always** is with legal stuff? :) More seriously, it's a totally awesome question, and one of the very few that genuinely deserved to end up on Hot Network Questions list on its own merit and not just because it fits a formula. So thanks for asking it!

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to legal.SE? (I kid)

Comment: @Azor-Ahai It already has a home there too :-) http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6121/who-legally-owns-millenium-falcon-now

Comment: Oh. I thought they wouldn't take to that fictional of a question...

Comment: @TobiaTesan, oops, sorry. Since I  can't put spoiler tags in comments, I deleted it. Though why did you click in a star wars question without watching it first.

Comment: Government registration, tax files and titles to the Falcon were probably lost with the destruction of the Hosnian System, perhaps older documentation could be found on Coruscant.

Comment: First it belonged to George Lucas, but then he lost it to Mickey Mouse during a Sabacc game.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm going to go for #3 answer. **It wasn't Chewie or Rey**. Doesn't matter who was a pilot or co-pilot.

Upon Han's death as owner, the ownership, by any sensible legal standards<sup>[1], [2], [3]</sup>, passes NOT to Chewie (who is merely a First Mate, a **hired/crew** position<sup>[4]</sup> - and was never in any canon indicated to have been part-owner); but to the **estate inheritance line**.

- If there is an explicit will mentioning it, it passes to whoever is stated in the will.

  Personally I **do NOT see *THE* Han Solo making a will with a lawyer**.

  Therefore, we have two standard inheritance possibilities:
- If Han and Leia were still married, then **Leia becomes Falcon's owner**
- If Han and Leia were divorced, then the oldest surviving child becomes the owner - which to the best of the current canon knowledge is **Ben Organa-or-Solo, aka Kylo Ren**

Since [we know from the script](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113222/are-han-and-leia-still-married/113223#113223) that they are still married,

### ...the answer is: ***General Leia Organa***.

<sub>Please see notes #2 and #4 below for discussion of Chewie. Specifically, pertinent TL;DR is: if he wasn't a co-owner before by explicit sharing agreement with Han (which never existed or was mention in any SW canon), then he doesn't become an owner on Han's death. However, even if he was 1/2-owner due to some obscure EU fact I'm not aware of, he only retains his own 1/2 ownership; with Han's 1/2 going to Leia</sub>

---

---

[1] - I'm making an assumption that the baseline laws in New Republic would broadly mirror Earth law *unless it clashes with in-universe information*. I'm also making an assumption that since Disney, JJAbrams and Disney's lawyers are all in USA, they'd use US laws assumptions as this is what they know.

[2] - To confirm that First Mate wouldn't have any legal claims ahead of the wife, I [asked on law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6121/who-legally-owns-millenium-falcon-now) and it is a consensus that absent explicit ownership agreement with Chewie, he wouldn't have any claim (see #4 below for related point).

[3] - Since the question was raised in comments, I'll address it here: "[posession being 9/10ths of the law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_is_nine-tenths_of_the_law)" does **not** apply here. The actual legalistic wording of that folk expression is "*in the absence of clear and compelling testimony or documentation to the contrary* {{which is not the case here as Han and Leia are married}}, the person in actual, custodial possession of the property is presumed to be the rightful owner". Besides, in this case the on-paper owner happens to be a warlord, a head of government, AND a (at least unofficial) employer of the possessors. They OWN the law!

[4] - I'm not aware of ANY details in canon, or Legends, that even remotely indicates that Chewie was ever co-owner of the ship. He was First Mate - which simply means he's a member of the crew who is *second in command* after the Captain, but in and out of itself has nothing to do with ownership whatsoever. Obviously, if someone digs something to contradict that view from canon/EU, I will change my position. However, as per Law.SE experts, even in that extremely unlikely case, he does NOT take over Han's ownership share - he retains his and Leia takes over Han's.

Comment: Follow up question: does TGFFA even **have** a concept of a divorce in canon?

Comment: Follow up question: what makes you think TGFFA has the same concept of inheritance than the US?

Comment: @Ghanima - Canon: Kylo Ren thinks Vader's Lightsaber is "his" :) EU/Legends - saw mentions before.

Comment: Ok, good point ;)

Comment: Given that Han is described as the ship's "Captain-Owner", it would seem more likely that the Mate would take ownership rather than the Captain's wife.

Comment: @DVK - It would depend on what maritime tradition is at play and on what basis the ship was held in the first place.

Comment: @Richard - given it's an American director, writer, and company, I am going to assume they'd default to American laws as that's what they would be more familiar with, absent explicit indication otherwise. Although I'd just assume British Admiralty law is quite similar to US, except for rum.

Comment: @Richard - hopefully, [this](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6121/who-legally-owns-millenium-falcon-now) won't get closed as off-topic

Comment: I think your third bullet point is incorrect, as murdering someone automatically loses you the right to inherit from them (so Kylo Ren would be skipped over in the line of inheritance even if H&L were divorced).

Comment: Doesn't all of this only make sense if Han legally owned the Falcon? It's not clear to me that he did. When Han asks if (so-and-so) had it, Rey replies that she got it from someone who stole it from someone else who stole it from that person – so Han correctly knew that that person had had it. It may be that Han lost the Falcon in a bet or to a debt.

Comment: @KRyan - nope, Han explicitly said that the original whatshisname **stole** the Falcon from him, right after Rey recites the chain of theft. Come on, if you can't trust Han, who can you trust? Obi-Wan?

Comment: @DVK: So, *how* did that so-and-so steal the falcon? By being better at poker than Han thought possible?

Comment: @Deduplicator - winning at cards wouldn't be called "stealing" - at best, "cheating" (all nods to Lando's language don't count - his beef with Han wasn't winning at cards, it was using language-lawyering to choose Falcon when Lando didn't in any way intend Falcon to be part of the bet. That was covered in EU).

Comment: However, stealing ships in Star Wars, at least EU, is an old an honorable tradition. One Han himself engaged in as well, AND was a victim to, before. There's even ship-stealing in Disney  canon before Ep7

Comment: *"...the answer is: General Leia Organa"* who almost certainly immediately gives it to Chewbacca, or possibly Rey. :-)

Comment: I for one have no issue with assuming inheritance law in the New Republic is at least similar enough to the ones we have that this is the right answer, or right enough barring canon.

Comment: I'm going for answer #4, R2D2 owns it.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland - OK, I gotta hear your reasoning for that one please!

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To: However, Han is the type of guy who would say someone stole it, when in reality he means someone cheated at a poker game, thus stealing the pot (which may include the Falcon). Han doesn't mince words, so he'd be inclined to outright call that theft, in order to convey that it was unfairly taken from him.

Answer (score 24):

### We don't know who would technically legally own the Falcon at this point, but Rey has been made the de facto pilot by Chewbacca.

Especially since the "ownership" of the Millennium Falcon is primarily based on who currently possesses and captains it, it is not entirely unreasonable to assume that Rey now "owns" the ship.

From the novelization:

> In the cockpit, Rey headed for the copilot’s seat, only to find her way blocked by a massive, hirsute form. “Chewie, the Falcon flies better with two people at the controls, you know that. I’ve already sat in that seat. I’m ready to do so again.”
>
> A series of moans came from the Wookiee. Then he turned— and sat down. In the copilot’s seat.
>
> Rey felt herself tearing up. “You’re serious, aren’t you?”
>
> Chewie groaned and, to make certain she grasped his meaning, gestured to his left. Toward the pilot’s position.
>
> Sitting down, she settled herself in. She could do this. If Chewbacca felt she could do it, then who was she to dispute him? As she hesitated, the Wookiee reached over and mussed her hair. Grinning, she made a show of trying to slap his hand away. He had no idea how much this innocent, familial gesture meant to her. Behind them, R2-D2 beeped happily.
>
> Facing forward again, she completed a last scan of the console, assuring herself she knew where everything was. From experience, she knew that the Falcon was a forgiving ship. She intended to do right by it. Reaching out, she let her fingers play over the controls. Beside her, Chewie did likewise as he groaned his approval.
>
> The Millennium Falcon rose.

Comment: Ooh. Jr vs Sr novel fight!!! Let battle  be joined! I sense an awakening.

Comment: Upvoted this answer as it seems to be the only one that realizes that ownership in Star Wars has little to do with legality, especially in a time where the two "legal goverments" are at war with each-other.

Comment: @Theik - you're forgetting that **one of the 2 governments** is headed by who the rightful owner of the Falcon really is. That changes the picture slightly from "random joe a victim of 'posession being 99% of ownership" typical one. And the new pilots, at least via tacit acknowledgement, **work with/for that government**

Comment: Damn, Chewbacca... *wipes away tears*

Comment: I don't see that this novel snippet indicates that she's the captain, just that Chewie wants her to sit in the [pilot's seat](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/23/68/f4/2368f45afbcb96b22639f022d8cb7402.jpg).

Comment: @DVK that doesn't clarify if spouse or child gets the default inheritance... or for that matter if it more likely seen as a corporate asset that should go to the partner.

Comment: @MichaelT - please read the legal details [in the answers and some comments to my Law.SE question](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6121/who-legally-owns-millenium-falcon-now). **The experts** all agree that either it all goes to Leia 100%, OR, in the **never discussed in any level of canon and thus extremely unlikely event** of Chewie being official co-owner, he remains co-owner and Leia takes over Han's share. Unless someone shows me canon/EU proof of Chewie being anything but a second-in-command crew member, that means Leia 100%

Comment: @DVK don't you want to hear another "that is mine" bit from someone disputing the inheritance customs?

Comment: @MichaelT - I deeply and honestly don't know &^*t about law, and thus valiantly outsourced all my legal thinking to where it belongs instead of my poor legally-underequipped-brain :)

Comment: @DVK *Clearly* this needs to be migrated to Law.SE. Should be on topic since they won't give any real legal advice and only deal with hypotheticals.  Apparently historical legal precedents are on topic and this was a long, long time ago...

Comment: @MichaelT - Then it'd get closed as dupe of http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6121/who-legally-owns-millenium-falcon-now

Answer (score 6):

With the death of

> Han Solo

at that point, the ownership would presumably have gone to Chewbacca as nominal Captain with Rey as the ship's temporary co-pilot/First Mate.

Note that Chewbacca told her where to sit

> Rey glanced at the Falcon. Chewbacca had almost completed his exterior flight check. “I know what we’re doing is right,” Rey said. “This is how it has to be. This is how it should be.”
>   “I know it, too,” Leia said. “May the Force be with you.” She moved back and smiled as Rey boarded.
>   Rey took the pilot’s seat, which was where Chewbacca had asked her to sit. Despite the old cushioning, she felt comfortable in it. - <sub><sup>[SW: The Force Awakens - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Since Rey's plan is to spend the next x years studying the ways of the Force with Luke, it's unlikely that the ship will remain in her custody.

Comment: "Chewbacca told her where to sit."  And it's not wise to upset a Wookie; they have been known to tear off manipulative appendages.

Answer (score 0):

The scrap dealer that was trading food for scrap and other items claimed to own it. If Han Solo actually owned it and he acquired it legally then that would be true but since Han Solo did not indicate it was sold he must have been the rightful owner. Chewbacca now owns it.

Answer (score 0):

The New Republic owns it.
The Empire became owner by capturing it in New Hope under a Confiscation Act. The fact that Han stole it back doesn't make his ownership legal.

Comment: Hi Vincent. Are you sure your answer adds new information on what was already said? If yes, could you add some references, links?

Answer (score -3):

I'd like to propose an answer more based in science-fiction or magic:

The owner of the Millennium Falcon is whoever the Millennium Falcon chooses.

As we imagine times and places where artificial intelligence (or magic intelligence) may equal or surpass sentient biological intelligence, An A.I. may get the right and responsibility to choose their biological partner.

We have plenty of stories in which the magic object (or sufficiently advanced technology) decides for itself who gets to use it. For example, the wands in Harry Potter are known to choose their wizard.

Comment: Droids in Star Wars don't get to choose their owners.

Comment: Can you support this with any canon support?  I.e., examples of that kind of thing from the movies, extended universe (Legends), etc?  Although an interesting idea, it would be a much better answer with some support from one media or another.