# Are Han and Leia still married?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

We know they

> separated after Ben became Kylo Ren

But are they separated but still married, or divorced?

Comment: Kylo Rey? Now that's one hell of a spoiler.

Comment: @Richard - ... and THAT is how you virally spread new fan theories :)

Comment: It's as if Abrams named them this way on purpose....

Comment: Is there anything that indicates they *were* married? I don't recall them referring to each other as husband / wife?

Comment: @TZHX, yeah the movie said nothing about their marital status (hence the question). It is clear that they were together for years and had a child. EU/Legends has them married, but of course, that's different.

Answer (score 27):

The film's novelisations would seem to strongly indicate that they have remained married.

- Per the [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))

> ***Husband and wife stood regarding each other for the first time in
> years.** Amid the smoke and drifting embers, neither said a word.
> Emerging from behind the figure in the portal, C-3PO walked out into
> the scorched field to confront the motionless droid beside Han.*

and

> ***Left alone again, husband and wife also embraced.** Han murmured over
> her shoulder, “I saw him. He was here.”*

- Per the [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))

> ***Once the droids were gone, husband and wife shared a moment together,
> alone.** “You changed your hair,” Han said. She raised an eye at his
> outfit. “Same jacket.”*
>
> [later]
>
> *“I’ll get you there,” Han said, without hesitation.
>
> **General Organa turned to her husband.** “Han, how?”
>
> Han gave her the same crooked grin Finn had seen him give Rey. “If I told you, you wouldn’t like it.”*

and

> *Moments before the command center holoscreens had relayed the detonations, she had felt the sharpest and deepest of pains. As if her heart had ruptured. **Her husband. Han. He was gone.** Those who knew Leia considered her to be someone who had suffered much yet had always emerged from that suffering stronger and wiser. But immersed in her present grief, Leia found no strength. She found no wisdom. She found only anguish and emptiness. She’d failed to prevent her son from succumbing to the darkness of Darth Vader. **Now her husband was dead. Her brother lost.***

Comment: I really want to know which (and read it) script version the novelization is based off of. But I can't ask yet.

Comment: @DVK - I've only seen one script version.

Comment: @DVK  - The blurb for the Junior novel states that it was based on the Screenplay, but a careful reading of the first few pages would suggest that it's actually an adaptation **of the official novelisation**.

Comment: once the insanity of SF7 post volume dies down, and in the unlikely event i'm still on this site, please be prepared to see (and hopefully answer) the question that I had for the last couple of months - what are the general rules for basis of Sr vs. Jr. novelizations for star wars. To me it smells like pre-Ep7 junior ones were explicitly based on later scripts.

Comment: @DVK - I've twitted at the author. Hopefully he'll enlighten us. I'm seeing lots of detail in the junior novel that's not in the script but was in the ADF novel.

Comment: knowing you, **you** might actually get a response. NONE of my contact attempts to any creators about questions on this site ever succeed so I basically gave up.

Comment: @DVK - I've found that the key is to go in with no expectations, ask very politely and not to expect an immediate response. The "*what are all these time-machines?*" response I got took nearly 6 months to arrive, but when it did, completely answered the question.

Comment: does that mean that, at the earliest try of 3 years ago, I should now stop waiting by the fire patiently? :)

Comment: @DVK - Or sockpuppet an account and ask again.

Comment: wouldn't that fit the clinical definition of insanity? Try and try again if you fail? :)

Comment: @DVK - Would you rather be sane or have lots of rep?

Comment: I pick "both" :)

Answer (score 14):

According to [Writers Guild of America (WGA) leaked script](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-the-force-awakens-ending/), they are still "husband and wife", meaning **still married**.

> And standing there is LEIA.
>   She sees Han and is stunned. A silent beat, **husband and
>   wife reunited** for the first time in years. In the smoke and embers, no one says a word.